# Python: How to compare two hours

Tags: python

I need to call a function, exactly `08:00, 18:00, 22:00` hours. I've created a example to test the comparison between hours. When the current time reaches one of those horary. Put in inside a While loop thinking this example would work as a stopwatch, but I think I'm wrong. How is the best way to compare those values?

```
currentH= dt.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
h = "16:15:10"
while True:
    if(currentH==h):
        print 'Ok'
print 'The current Hour is: '+h
```

Comment: nothing changes in your loop: infinite loop all right. and also busy (no delays).

Comment: Add a `break` after `print 'Ok'`

Comment: I'd to know the reason about downvote, because I can update the question

Comment: @MauroBaraldi It never goes in `IF`, that's one problem

Comment: As a side note: is there a reason you don't want to use an off-the-shelf scheduling library, or just use your OS's scheduler to run your script?

Comment: no no, actually, I'm using schedule module, but I need to update my question with more information. Do you care if take a time to update my question? I'll make it simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime as dt
import time
currentH= dt.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).time()

hrs = ['00:02', '12:00']
for i in range(len(hrs)):
    h = [int(x) for x in hrs[i].split(':')]
    h = dt.datetime.now().replace(hour=h[0], minute=h[1], second=0,microsecond=0).time()
    hrs[i] = h

while True:
    currentH = dt.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).time()
    print(currentH)
    if currentH in hrs:
        print('Time is now',currentH)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: This doesn't solve any of the problems with the OP's code, it just replaces his working parsing code with more complicated parsing code. It still loops forever using 100% CPU without ever matching.

Comment: Also, it adds a new problem: after 00:00:00, the time has passed, but your code says the time will come.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem with your code is that you never call `now()` again inside the loop, so you're just spinning forever comparing the initial time to `16:15:10`.

While we're at it: Why convert the time to a string for comparison instead of just comparing times?

But there are bigger problems with this design that can't be fixed as easily.

What happens if you check the time at 16:15, then go to sleep, then wake up at 16:25? Then `now()` never returns 16:15:10.

Also, do you really want to burn 100% CPU for 10 hours?

A better solution is to write a `sleep_until` function:

```
def sleep_until(target):
    left = target - dt.datetime.now()
    if left > dt.timedelta(seconds=0):
        time.sleep(left.total_seconds())
```

(If you're using Python 2.7 or 3.4, it's a bit more complicated, because `sleep` will wake up early if there's a signal. But to handle that case, you just need to add a `while True:` loop around the whole thing.)

Now, the only tricky bit is working out the first time you need to sleep until, which isn't all that tricky:

```
waits = itertools.cycle(dt.timedelta(hours=wait) for wait in (10, 4, 10))
now = dt.datetime.now()
start = dt.datetime.combine(dt.date.today(), dt.time(hour=8))
for wait in waits:
    start += wait
    if start > now:
       break
```

And now, we just loop over the waits forever, sleeping until each next time:

```
for wait in waits:
    sleep_until(start)
    print('Time to make the donuts')
    start += wait
```

Or, of course, you could just grab one of the many scheduling libraries off PyPI.

Or just use your platform's cron/launchd/Scheduled Tasks API to run your script.